# Running Ubuntu from USB stick on Chromebook

Tags: usb-drive, chromebook

I have a bootable USB stick with the latest Ubuntu on it. To create this bootable pen I used Rufus in Windows 10.  Is it possible to use this flashpen on my Chromebook? Or do I need to have produced it on Chromebook first?  I do not know how to make the Chromebook boot from flashdrive. There are no F keys on the Chromebook so the idea of pressing F12 key during boot-up is out of the question.

Comment: This typically involves putting the chromebook into developer mode, there are multiple ways to put Linux on the device. The process isn't nearly as easy as a typical Ubuntu install, there are quite a few tutorials out there you can easily find with google search though, so I'd suggest reading a few of these first and then maybe update your question with the parts that you didn't fully understand. It is a really broad subject, and I fear you'll not get much help unless the question is a bit more specific.

Comment: It depends on what kind of processor the Chromebook has. Arm processors won't boot from USB live Ubuntu meant for Intel/AMD processors.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, this is no easy task :(

Comment: The specific question: can the (Ubuntu) bootable usb pen prepared by Windows 10 be used to run Ubuntu on laptops with any OS, such as Mac or Chromebook?